# Can Mockito mock a package-level visibility interface?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class using a bean of type `interface` with [package-level visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). I have to write unit tests for that class, but mocking the interface fails every time with the message:

> Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes

I tried to make the interface public for testing purposes, and the tests passed without issues.

Is there any way to configure Mockito to mock a non-public interface?

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a rare situation, you might be able to get by through extending the interface with a token public child interface in order to increase the visibility:

```
public TestPublicInterface extends DefaultInterface {}
```

Then you could test using the token interface:

```
Mockito.mock(TestPublicInterface.class)
```